# Why does my second jQuery anonymous function not run when called?

Tags: jquery

Take a look at this piece code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('a.upvote-off').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('upvote-off').addClass('upvote-on');
    });
    $('a.upvote-on').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('upvote-on').addClass('upvote-off');
    });
});
```

It's a simple jQuery toggle function which removes a class `upvote-off` of an anchor tag, then replaces it with `upvote-on`. Likewise, the second portion of the code reverses the initial code when the same icon is clicked on again. The default value of the anchor tag is `upvote-off`.

The first portion of the function runs:

```
$('a.upvote-off').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('upvote-off').addClass('upvote-on');
});
```

However, the second doesn't work:

```
$('a.upvote-on').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('upvote-on').addClass('upvote-off');
});
```

Yet, if I comment out the first portion, the second portion works. Why is this?

Note that I'm not using `.toggleClass()` because there's some more complex functionality I want to add in to each at a later point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're binding your handlers only to the elements that have the specified classes when the page is first loaded. If an element's class changes, the bindings don't automatically follow it.

To solve this, use delegation with `.on()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).on('click', 'a.upvote-off', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('upvote-off').addClass('upvote-on');
    });
    $(document).on('click', 'a.upvote-on', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('upvote-on').addClass('upvote-off');
    });
});
```

If there's a smaller DIV that encloses all the upvote elements, replace `document` with that ID to minimize the overhead of this.

Comment: The important thing to understand is that `$("selector")` just returns the elements that match the selector at the time that it's run. So if elements are added later, or attributes change dynamically, they won't be in the collection that was made at the beginning of the script.

Comment: All that being said, do not worry about binding one event for each state. Bind only one click event, then you toggle and check for the class on or off on your unique click handler to run separate logic.

Comment: @HugoSilva He said in his question that there are other differences, that's why he doesn't use toggle.

Comment: Sorry @Barmar, maybe I didn't put it very well. He could use toggle and yet have separate logic for each state. 
What can be done this way:

    $('.on').click(logic1);
    $('.off').click(logic2);

That couldn't be done this way?

    $(el).click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
        if($(this).hasClass('on')){
           logic1
        }else{
           logic2
        }
    });

Comment: Yeah, you can do that, but it seems more complicated than just having two `.on()` calls that do the appropriate thing.

Comment: If it is the same element and the same event, I wouldn't bind it twice. From an event binding perspective, that sounds more complicated to me, and that is why I suggested one binding, because that is what he seemed to be struggling with. Anyway, good answer, solved the problem!

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're suggesting, since code in comments is unreadable. If you think there's a better or alternative way to do it, post it as an answer.